# Get other product names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select to get an user NEW sells:

```
select 'sells' prefix, p.product_name, k.user, MAX(c.data) as data, c.user, count(c.user)
from sells c
  inner join products p on c.id = p.id 
  inner join cadastro k on c.user = k.id 
where c.user='1' and c.data > now()
```

I show something like this:

```
You sell (p.product_name) and more 4 (count(c.user)) products
```

**Ok, my select is pretty good for this. the problem is, I want to show the other 4 products names**

Like this:

```
You sell (p.product_name 1) and more 4 (count(c.user)) products:
product 2, product 3, product 4 and product 5
```

How can I get this other products names (if I sell more than 1 product, of course)?

Comment: group_concat perhaps?

Comment: oh, I don't know how to use group_concat and even if it solves this @jarlh